# What can I do if I am angry with everything in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, faq-proposed

> This is a **proposed FAQ** question for those tearing their hair out on Stack Exchange sites.

Recently I asked a question and gave a bounty but nobody gave a good answer. I asked for help on Meta Stack Overflow, but with Streisand effect those answers only got upvotes! I decided to delete the question on Meta Stack Overflow, but the system forbade me...

*(three thousand more words)*

I am being driven crazy. What do I do?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: +1 for the amazing answer you've got

Comment: "What can I do if I am angry with everything in Stack Overflow" - Create a mandelbrot set?

Comment: +2 for the most constructive way to express those "3000 words"! And with at least as much meaning that way as when people usually do it!

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Looks like moderators have option to double vote on a post. o.O

Comment: @hims056 Oops... busted! I think I've accidentally spoken about Fight Club... I'm in trouble, now! (But at least I didn't reveal that we can *actually* vote up to 5 times! That would have been really bad!)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I can up-vote as much as I want if I can hack the database.

Comment: @johnchen902 Don't confuse Moderators with Managers, Developers, or Administrators. Moderators have no access to the database at all, while the other three could. Managers, in particular, regularly use such access to fix and investigate things that are beyond moderators' tools.

Comment: @johnchen902 hehe... I figured you knew, but you know what they say about assuming! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Edited the comment. (Changed the subject)

Comment: How is it "Streisand effect" when there does not seem to be "an attempt to hide, remove, or censor a piece of information"?

Comment: @doubleDown I didn't post the whole event. (Maybe you can find it in those *three thousand more words*)

Comment: How can I do so when I don't even know what those "three thousand more words" are referring to?

Comment: @doubleDown I just meant I *don't* want you to know the whole event.

Comment: I'm saying you are misunderstanding what "Streisand effect" means, i.e. "Streisand effect" doesn't make sense in this context "**I asked for help on Meta Stack Overflow, but with Streisand effect those answers only got upvotes**"

Comment: @doubleDown "I asked for help on Meta Stack Overflow, and I ####-##### ### ###### ## ### ######## #########, but with Streisand effect those answers only got up-votes." Again I don't want anyone more know what had happened.

Comment: `I decided to delete the question on Meta Stack Overflow, but the system forbade me.` This is sooo annoying! I can't close the downvotes and my rep drain! ;(

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Calm down. Follow these steps:

1. Leave here for a while. Best ways:

   - [Log out of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout)
   - Shut down your computer.
2. Make yourself comfortable:

   - If you are thirsty, drink something.
   - If you are hungry, eat something.
   - If you are tired after a day's work, sleep or take a nap.
   - If the weather is too hot for you, turn on an air conditioner.
   - If the weather is too cold for you, turn on a heater.
   - If your chair is too hard for you, go and sit on a sofa.
   - ...
3. Let yourself temporarily forget everything:

   - Play game with your smartphone or tablet.
   - Go to Twitter, Facebook, Line or something similar (except Stack Overflow).
   - Go outside, but not on a typhoon day.
   - Do some math, unless you can do math without all of your brainpower.
   - Watch television or read newspapers or books.
   - Sleep or take a nap.
   - ...
4. Estimate how much reputation you have lost:

   - [All bounties are paid for up front.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)
   - If more than 30% of votes on your posts are upvotes, then you will gain reputation.
   - Even if you did lose reputation, it will be regained by answering more questions.
   - ...
5. Recall every maxim you have learned. This section is culture-dependent:

   - A poem in Traditional Chinese:

     > 千里送書只為牆，
     >     讓他三尺又何妨。
     >     長城萬里今尤在，
     >     不見當年秦始皇。
   - A haiku in Japanese:

     > 古池や
     >       蛙飛びこむ
     >       水の音
   - A fable in French:

     > Un jour un Coq détourna
     >       Une perle qu’il donna
     >       Au beau premier Lapidaire.
     >       Je la crois fine, dit-il,
     >       Mais le moindre grain de mil
     >       Seroit bien mieux mon affaire.
     >
     > Un ignorant hérita
     >       D’un manuscrit qu’il porta
     >       Chez son voisin le Libraire.
     >       Je crois, dit-il, qu’il est bon ;
     >       Mais le moindre ducaton
     >       Seroit bien mieux mon affaire.
   - (Can you help add more languages?)

Comment: I like step 2 a lot. Practical, widely applicable, straightforward to implement, and likely to get results. I guess you don't have a translation for the poem, huh?

Comment: "If you are thirsty, drink something.
If you are hungry, eat something." OH WOW thank you so much! Where did you learn this amazing knowledge?! :P

Comment: @JoshCaswell I can translate it, but the translation will be ugly. (My English is not good enough)

Comment: That's all right; just curiosity.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The poem roughly means: Send letter for thousands of miles only for a wall. / Does it matter if you let him three feet? / The Great Wall is still there today, / but the Emperor is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Yup, I can't say I understand that one. Thanks a lot for the effort, though!

Comment: How do I go to Twitter (Step 3) when I shut down my computer in Step-1? :D

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya Smart phone or tablet..

Comment: -1 for sleeping me twice.

Comment: Where's the part about ragequitting?

Comment: You don't have any real life friends? The best way for me to release the anger is to whine at a friend/friends.

Comment: Go to PHP room for a whine helps too, or the in most popular chat on meta.

Comment: @Telkitty猫咪咪 Going to PHP room or a meta room violates the first step: Log out of Stack Overflow. However it may help if you are angry with something else.

Comment: Meh. Do we really need a FAQ question that tells people to calm down and log off if they are riled by Stack Overflow?

Comment: @MartinSmith That was my first thought as well, but then I remembered how many times I've asked someone to calm down on Meta and... yes, we kinda need this. Unfortunately.

Comment: You forgot "PROFIT" after the ellipses!

Comment: Nice poem. I'm Chinese but that's the first time I've heard of it.

Comment: As I read number 2, all I could imagine was Forest Gump saying "When I got tired, I slept. When I got hungry, I ate. When I had to go, you know, I went."

Answer (score 5):

Context for poem:

Found at http://www.immanuel.net/cincc/chinese_worship/chinese_worship.asp?WorshipId=1252&Action=DETAIL:

In an old section of the the town, Tongcheng, Anhui, there is a monument with two characters, “Comity” inscribed on it.  Below the momument, it is a six-foot wide alley with granite walls on both sides paved with stone tiles. There is a tree that gives shade and is full of the scent of flowers, it’s a beautiful ancient place to visit.  At the entrance, is a stone tablet inscribed “Six-foot Lane” embedded in the wall. According to legend, during the Qing Dynasty of Emperor Kangxi, the head of the Educational Department, Zhang Ying lived there.  Once his family had a dispute with a neighbor over a fence that incroached three-foot of their land. The family wrote a letter and delievered it to Zhang Ying at the capital to ask him to use his power to settle the case.  Minister Zhang wrote a poem: “A letter from thousand miles, just for a wall that yields three-foot of no harm. The Great Wall still stands, but where is Qin Shi Huang?”  The Zhang’s got the letter and made peace with their neighbor.